# CodeIgniter Parser Template - Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out another way to do what I want to do.

I have a default html file for all pages of my project, in which depending on the area of my project I am accessing is inserted different JS files, until then ok.

What I'm trying to find a better way to develop is to instantiate a new "Noty" after the view 'users / users-add' is rendered.

How could I do without having to pass the `{javascript_code}` attribute to the view?

I hope you guys can understand my doubt...

**Edit: I forgot to say... I wanted to put the Javascript code in the view and not in the Template. However, if I put in the View I will get error that "Noty is not defined" because the file is loaded at the end.**

---

End of my `starter.php default template:`

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/js/core/libraries/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/js/core/libraries/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

{javascript}
    {script}
{/javascript}

{javascript_code} // Here where I want instantiate a new "Noty"

</body>
```

`

---

How I'm doing in `controller:`

```
$page_content = $this->load->view('users/users-add', NULL, TRUE);
$data = array(
        'page_content' => $page_content,
        'javascript'   => array(
                            array('script' => '<script src="' . base_url() . 'assets/js/plugins/notifications/noty.min.js"></script>')),
        'css'          => array(
                            array('script' => '<link href="' . base_url() . 'assets/css/noty.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">')),
        'javascript_code' => '<script>new Noty({
                                text: "Some notification text",
                              }).show();</script>'
    );

    $this->parser->parse('default/starter', $data);
```

Comment: Is `{javascript_code}` creating the HTML you're expecting? Is the Noty error a browser console error? Can you explain the why behind why you don't want to just have the script included in the view without all this parsing logic? There might be a better solution you're not considering.

Comment: In the template there are some JS files that are for every page of my project. But there are specific views where I need to load JS files specific to them. And so, I need small and specific JS code inside the View, however in this example, the Noty file is loaded there at the end ... That is, I have the template, when I call the view it is inserted inside the template, But in the view I need to use Noty - which is loaded at the end of the Template.

Comment: I think my comment was EXTREMELY confusing. But in short: in the template there are JS files for all pages. In `$ this-> parser-> parse ('default / starter', $ data);` `the array` $ data` is inserted inside the template - which `javascript` is inserted before the end of` . However, I VERY need to use "Noty" inside View - which, in my example, is inserted at the end of the template ... And for that reason I can not use "Noty" in View.

Comment: I've made a dozen CodeIgniter projects and I've never needed to use `$this->parser->parse()`. You do know if you can call `$this->load->view()` multiple times, once for the header, once for the nav, body, footer, so on. You should put the html in a view file, and then use `$this->load->view()` to call it. You can put it inside an if statement if you only want to call it sometimes, or pass $data into it and use some logic in the view. Not sure if this helps. I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. Good luck!